# Flex AIR SwfLoader CPU Usage > 50% problem

Tags: apache-flex, air, cpu, swfloader

I have an AIR application, I use SwfLoader to load another swf file to display in this app. The problem is the CPU Usage always takes over 50%, but it only takes 15% when the swf file runs in standalone mode.

Does anyone meet this issue? Please give me some advices. Thanks a lot

Comment: I see the problem, because I use the transparent=true in the window, so it gets a lot of CPU. I set to 'false' and it is ok now.

Thanks God.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WOW, you were so right. Thank you binhdocco for posting your solution! It just solved a major issue at my job.

Adobe, This is a horrible bug! Why even have the window.transparent property if its going to run at 50% CPU on Windows?!?! #FAIL